# Marker rotation in Highchart

Tags: highcharts

Is there some way to rotate each marker by different-different angles?

lets say , In the following example, In series 1, the image markers should hv (30, 90)  and in series 2, (150, 60) degree rotations respectively.

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.05,
            maxPadding: 0.05
        },

        series: [{
            data: [
                {
                y: 29.9,
                    x:0,
                   marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
                }
            }, 
                {
                y: 71.9,
                    x:1,
                   marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
                }
            },  
                [3, 106.4]
            ]
        },
                {
            data: [
                {
                y: 60,
                    x:0,
                   marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
                }
            }, 
                {
                y: 25,
                    x:1,
                   marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/snow.png)'
                }
            },  
                [3, 90]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

[Code example](http://jsfiddle.net/jUnkL/1/)

Comment: use this (//jsfiddle.net/gvTWf/1/) may be helpful for you.

Comment: Sandy, saw that fiddle already, is not helpful in my jsfiddle example... Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Sur can you describe your query in little more explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not officially supported, but you can use workaround, which iterate on each point and rotate by `attr()` function. It is not perfect, but you can use translate to move markers.

http://jsfiddle.net/yd8hV/2/

```
 $.each(chart.series[0].data,function(i,point){

        if(!point.angle)
            point.angle = 0;

        this.graphic.attr({
            rotation:point.angle
        })
        .translate(10,-10);

    });
```

Comment: Is there an update that works with current version? I am not seeing any effect on the symbol rotation in this example

Comment: You can try to use .css() method and for example 'transform': 'rotate(7deg)'